# Java ArrayList printing out empty?

Tags: java, arraylist

My problem is simple. When sending the value of x when input == 1, the method is supposed to add the value of x into the al ArrayList. It does this, but when I attempt to print the values of al , it prints out empty.

First class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ToDo {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner g = new Scanner(System.in);

    void start() {
        IncompleteTasks incompletetasks = new IncompleteTasks();
        CompleteTasks completetasks = new CompleteTasks();
        AllTasks alltasks = new AllTasks();
        int input = 999;
        String x = "";

        while (input != 0) {

            System.out.println("What would you like to do? Type '0' to cancel");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("1. Add a task"); // done
            System.out.println("2. View current tasks");
            System.out.println("3. Delete a task"); // done
            input = s.nextInt();
            if (input == 1) {
                while (!x.equals("quit")) {
                    System.out.print("Enter a task: (Type 'quit' to finish! ");
                    x = g.nextLine();
                    if (x.equals("quit")) {
                        start();
                    }
                    else {
                        incompletetasks.IncompleteTasksAdd(x);
                    }

                }

            }
            else if (input == 2) {
                System.out.println("\t1. All  Tasks");
                System.out.println("\t2. Complete Tasks");
                System.out.println("\t3. Incomplete Tasks");
                input = s.nextInt();
                if (input == 1) {
                    alltasks.AllTasks();
                }
                else if (input == 2) {
                    completetasks.CompleteTasks();
                }
                else if (input == 3) {
                    incompletetasks.IncompleteTasksDisplay();
                }
                else if (input == 0) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tInvalid choice! Try again!");
                    start();
                }
            }

            else if (input == 3) {
                System.out.println("hello");
                x = s.nextLine();
                incompletetasks.IncompleteTasksDelete(x);
            }
            else if (input == 0) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("\t\t\t\tInvalid choice! Try again!");
                start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IncompleteTasks {

    int counter = 0;
    Scanner g = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    void IncompleteTasksDisplay() {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
        for (String f : al) {
            counter++;
            System.out.println(f);
            // System.out.println(counter+". " +al.get(f));
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");

    }

    void IncompleteTasksAdd(String x) {
        al.add(x);
        System.out.println("\tTask Added!");
    }

    void IncompleteTasksDelete(String x) {
        for (int k = 0 ; k < al.size() ; k++) {
            if (al.get(k) == x) {
                al.remove(x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
What would you like to do? Type '0' to cancel

1. Add a task
2. View current tasks
3. Delete a task
1
Enter a task: (Type 'quit' to finish! Test
Task Added!
Enter a task: (Type 'quit' to finish! Test 1
Task Added!
Enter a task: (Type 'quit' to finish! Test 2
Task Added!
Enter a task: (Type 'quit' to finish! quit
What would you like to do? Type '0' to cancel

1. Add a task
2. View current tasks
3. Delete a task
2
1. All  Tasks
2. Complete Tasks
3. Incomplete Tasks
3
----------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------
What would you like to do? Type '0' to cancel

1. Add a task
2. View current tasks
3. Delete a task
```

I am new to java, so don't be surprised if I have bad coding in other sections or if I'm missing something very obvious. I appreciate all the help I can get, as I'm stumped, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but why dont you use switch case instead of if else if..

Comment: I've heard about a switch case but I have not learned it yet though its a priority of mine so I will learn it very soon. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Consume nextLine() after calling nextInt(). Then you won't need two Scanner instances. e.g. `input = s.nextInt(); s.nextLine();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
IncompleteTasks incompletetasks = new IncompleteTasks();
```

declares a *local* variable `incompletetasks`, specific to the current call to `start()`, and initializes it to a new empty list of tasks.

This line:

```
start();
```

creates a new, separate call to `start()`, which will therefore have a separate `incompletetasks` variable, and will not have any information about the `incompletetasks` variable that you've been adding everything to.

There's no real reason that `start()` should need to call itself.

The quickest way to fix this is to change this:

```
while (input != 0){
```

to this:

```
mainloop: while (input != 0) {
```

(where `mainloop` is a *label*, giving the while-loop a name so that you can refer to it) and almost every occurrence of this:

```
start();
```

to this:

```
continue mainloop;
```

(meaning roughly, "go back to the beginning of the loop named `mainloop`").

A *better* fix is to split out your method into smaller parts. That will allow for much clearer code. In general, it's usually best for a method not to have nested loops (though there are plenty of exceptions, so don't take that as a hard rule).

Comment: Awesome dude, fixed the issue, I am new to constructors but I kind of get what you mean, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Tacent , if you got  the solution , you should accept the answer. Just click on the correct sign.